# Scatter Plot not plotting using Managers for multiprocessing

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, python-multiprocessing

This program shows no error yet it produces a blank plot without any points. I later on wish to modify this code so that many processes can work in parallel to change the shared matplotlib scatter plot.

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager, NamespaceProxy
from multiprocessing import Process
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plotter(res):
    print(res.ax,res.fig)
    res.ax.scatter(np.random.normal(0,20,(100,)),np.random.uniform(0,20,(100,)),s=1)
    res.fig.savefig('man2.png')


class PlotClass():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    def __init__(self):
        print('Test') 


class MyManager(BaseManager):
    pass

class MyAttProxy(NamespaceProxy):
    # We need to expose the same __dunder__ methods as NamespaceProxy,
    _exposed_ = ('__getattribute__', '__setattr__', '__delattr__')

MyManager.register('Plot', PlotClass,MyAttProxy)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = MyManager()
    manager.start()
    plotscat = manager.Plot()
    pr = Process(target=plotter,args=(plotscat,))
    pr.start()
    pr.join()
    plotscat.fig.savefig('fig.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should re draw the figure after you add the scatter

```
def plotter(res):
    print(res.ax,res.fig)
    res.ax.scatter(np.random.normal(0,20,(100,)),np.random.uniform(0,20,(100,)),s=1)
    res.fig.canvas.draw_idle()
    res.fig.savefig('man2.png')
```

Comment: Your solution isn't solving the problem.